Calling Wordpress PHP route within an IFrame
I want an add to cart functionality within an iFrame that is built on my local drive (localhost3000). There exists a route in the wordpress site that hosts it, but I am not sure how to bypass COORS regulations so I can do this.
This is my current code for within the iFrame: `
const InfoCard: React.FC<InfoCardProps> = ({ description, price, details, productId, actionUrl, sx }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Initialize the necessary parameters for WooCommerce AJAX functionality
    window.woocommerce_params = {
      wc_ajax_url: 'https://crm.emergente.com.co/staging/?wc-ajax=%%endpoint%%'
    };
  }, []);

  const handleAddToCart = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      product_id: productId,
      quantity: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: window.woocommerce_params.wc_ajax_url.replace('%%endpoint%%', 'add_to_cart'),
      data: data,
      beforeSend: function () {
        // Disable the button and show loading state
        $(e.currentTarget).prop('disabled', true).addClass('loading');
      },
      complete: function () {
        // Re-enable the button and remove loading state
        $(e.currentTarget).prop('disabled', false).removeClass('loading').addClass('added');
      },
      success: function (response) {
        if (response.error && response.product_url) {
          window.location.href = response.product_url;
          return;
        }

        // Trigger the WooCommerce added_to_cart event
        $(document.body).trigger('added_to_cart', [response.fragments, response.cart_hash, $(e.currentTarget)]);

        // Update the cart fragments
        if (response.fragments) {
          $.each(response.fragments, function (key, value) {
            $(key).replaceWith(value);
          });
        }

        alert('Product added to cart!');
      },
      error: function () {
        alert('Failed to add product to cart');
      }
    });
  };


Also, here is my add to cart event listener code (found by inspecting the main page):
jQuery(function(e){if("undefined"==typeof wc_cart_fragments_params)return!1;var t=!0,r=wc_cart_fragments_params.cart_hash_key;try{t="sessionStorage"in window&&null!==window.sessionStorage,window.sessionStorage.setItem("wc","test"),window.sessionStorage.removeItem("wc"),window.localStorage.setItem("wc","test"),window.localStorage.removeItem("wc")}catch(f){t=!1}function n(){t&&sessionStorage.setItem("wc_cart_created",(new Date).getTime())}function o(e){t&&(localStorage.setItem(r,e),sessionStorage.setItem(r,e))}var a={url:wc_cart_fragments_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace("%%endpoint%%","get_refreshed_fragments"),type:"POST",data:{time:(new Date).getTime()},timeout:wc_cart_fragments_params.request_timeout,success:function(r){r&&r.fragments&&(e.each(r.fragments,function(t,r){e(t).replaceWith(r)}),t&&(sessionStorage.setItem(wc_cart_fragments_params.fragment_name,JSON.stringify(r.fragments)),o(r.cart_hash),r.cart_hash&&n()),e(document.body).trigger("wc_fragments_refreshed"))},error:function(){e(document.body).trigger("wc_fragments_ajax_error")}};function s(){e.ajax(a)}if(t){var i=null;e(document.body).on("wc_fragment_refresh updated_wc_div",function(){s()}),e(document.body).on("added_to_cart removed_from_cart",function(e,t,a){var s=sessionStorage.getItem(r);null!==s&&s!==undefined&&""!==s||n(),sessionStorage.setItem(wc_cart_fragments_params.fragment_name,JSON.stringify(t)),o(a)}),e(document.body).on("wc_fragments_refreshed",function(){clearTimeout(i),i=setTimeout(s,864e5)}),e(window).on("storage onstorage",function(e){r===e.originalEvent.key&&localStorage.getItem(r)!==sessionStorage.getItem(r)&&s()}),e(window).on("pageshow",function(t){t.originalEvent.persisted&&(e(".widget_shopping_cart_content").empty(),e(document.body).trigger("wc_fragment_refresh"))});try{var c=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(wc_cart_fragments_params.fragment_name)),_=sessionStorage.getItem(r),g=Cookies.get("woocommerce_cart_hash"),m=sessionStorage.getItem("wc_cart_created");if(null!==_&&_!==undefined&&""!==_||(_=""),null!==g&&g!==undefined&&""!==g||(g=""),_&&(null===m||m===undefined||""===m))throw"No cart_created";if(m){var d=1*m+864e5,w=(new Date).getTime();if(d<w)throw"Fragment expired";i=setTimeout(s,d-w)}if(!c||!c["div.widget_shopping_cart_content"]||_!==g)throw"No fragment";e.each(c,function(t,r){e(t).replaceWith(r)}),e(document.body).trigger("wc_fragments_loaded")}catch(f){s()}}else s();Cookies.get("woocommerce_items_in_cart")>0?e(".hide_cart_widget_if_empty").closest(".widget_shopping_cart").show():e(".hide_cart_widget_if_empty").closest(".widget_shopping_cart").hide(),e(document.body).on("adding_to_cart",function(){e(".hide_cart_widget_if_empty").closest(".widget_shopping_cart").show()}),"undefined"!=typeof wp&&wp.customize&&wp.customize.selectiveRefresh&&wp.customize.widgetsPreview&&wp.customize.widgetsPreview.WidgetPartial&&wp.customize.selectiveRefresh.bind("partial-content-rendered",function(){s()})});

Right now, when I click the add to cart, I get the success message but the cart is not actually updated.
